# Can't require('fs') in ember application

Tags: node.js, ember.js, brunch

I'm having trouble adding the line `require('fs')` anywhere in [ambari-web](https://github.com/apache/ambari/tree/trunk/ambari-web/app). I've tried adding it in ambari-web/app/app.js, ambari-web/app/controllers/wizard/step3_controller.js, and other places. Every time, I end up with

> Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "fs" from "app"

or something similar in Chrome's console log. What is going wrong, what misunderstandings do I have, and how can I add the fs module to this ember application so that I can use it in a controller? I've tried running following all of the [build instructions](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/AMBARI/Coding+Guidelines+for+Ambari) again after adding the module too -- without any luck.

Edit: is this a bad question? I'm getting downvoted, so let me know how to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fs` is a [Node.js module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) that is not available in browsers. There are various ways to emulate it in browsers, depending on what you're trying to do, but most likely to accomplish what you're attempting you'd need a separate Node.js program running that the web app makes requests to in order to trigger the file system operations you want to do.

Comment: From my understanding, Ember is a client-side framework. I don't understand what parts run on the server and what parts run in web browsers.

Comment: "Client-side" means in the web browser. I'm not familiar with ambari, but based on a very cursory review it appears it has a server-side (aka backend) application component written in Java and apparently some Python as well.

Comment: Most of my experience is with spring, javaee, .net, and flask. Ember is entirely new to me, so you're probably right that I'll have to add something outside of the ember webapp part. I suppose that answers my question; thanks for your help.